# Incorrect depth values

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, linear-algebra, glm-math

I have a problem with depth calculating.
VS shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 i_Pos;
layout(location = 5) in mat4 i_ModelMat;

uniform mat4 u_LightSpace;
uniform float u_FarPlane;
uniform float u_CutOff;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_LightSpace * i_ModelMat * vec4(i_Pos, 1.0f);
    
    gl_Position.xy /= tan(u_CutOff) * -gl_Position.z;
    gl_Position.z = (-gl_Position.z / u_FarPlane) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0f;
}
```

where:
u_LightSpace is a view matrix:
`glm::lookAt(pos, pos + dir, up), pos = {-2, -2, 2}, dir = {√2/2, √2/2, 0}, up = {-√2/2, √2/2, 0}`
u_FarPlane = 10
u_CutOff = π / 12      (15 degrees)

FS shader:

```
#version 330 core

void main()
{
    
}
```

Everything seems to be OK, however the depth buffer looks like:

[image]

Comment: By doing the perspective divide manually in the VS and setting w to 1, you screw up both the depth value interpolation as well as the clipping.

Comment: @derhass You're right, I let vertex post-processing to do the perspective divide and now everything is right